# Can I have aliases for embedded resources?

Tags: vb.net, embedded-resource

I have a set of embedded resources which would be images.

I receive an input string as such "image_1". Using this input string I load 2 images from my resources, image_1_1 and image_1_2.
For this I use ResourceManager.GetObject("image_1_1") etc..

Sometimes 2 or more resources has the same image_x_2, i.e: image_1_2 and image_5_2 is the same image.

How can I have an alias for image_1_2 and image_5_2 to point to the same embedded resource?
Instead of having 2 images of the same thing, which would take up more space.

**EDIT:**

Since this was not understood, I will provide pseudocode for you so you understand what I am trying to do.

```
'Imagine this input array of strings is big (50 - 100)
Dim InputString() as String = {"image_1", "image_2", "image_3"}
' image_1_2 and image_3_2 is the same image.
Dim image1 As Bitmap
Dim image2 As Bitmap

For Each str in InputString
    image1 = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(str + "_1")
    ' If this is image_3_2 it should point towards image_1_2.
    image2 = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(str + "_2")

    SomeClass.SomeArray.Add(New SomeImageHolderClass(image1, image2))
Next
```

Is it possible to edit this in the vbproj file? To have another name to the item?

```
<ItemGroup>
    <None Include="Resources\image_1_2.png" SomeOtherTagAsAlias="image_3_2" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Make a `Dictionary(Of String, String)` where the Key is the Alias and the Value is the mapped Resource name (so `[Dictionary]("image_1_2")` and `[Dictionary]("image_1_5")` return the same Value).

Comment: Please see my edited question.

Comment: Hello @Jimi, this solution is not what I am looking for. This would mean I have to load all of the images names manually (or atleast tag which ones are the same). Is it possible to have an alias for the embedded resource? Either in the vbproj file, or a different place?

Comment: @Jimi Let me know if the above is a possibility. Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand why would you prefer to edit these names in any place, but not a Dictionary. If you want to have an external file for some reason, build a JSON or XML file.

Comment: @Jimi Since it is already defined as a resource, adding an alias to it shouldn't have to be as hard as reading all resources into a dictionary, then giving aliases before checking that at a later point. What I meant with another place is not a random external file created just for this, but rather a file where the resource is already defined (i.e vbproj file..)

Comment: Why would a project have multiple resources that are the saame but with different names? Why not just reuse the same resource, and give it a good common name like "Common_DeleteIcon"? so you can have commonly used resources and specialized ones